# Using model versions in cocoapods

Tags: ios, core-data, cocoapods

I am using private pods while developing. In one of the private pods we have a Core Data Model (*.xcdatamodel). I have added a model version to this model, and update the model version in the inspector of the example pod project. In the main app, after running `pod update` the model version is not updated.

Is there a way to ensure the model version is correct for consumers of the pod?

Comment: did you run the application after pod update, at first run it should migrate the model?

Comment: I ran the app after pod update.